# Restart WPF application: wait untill new process is loaded before exiting the current process

Tags: c#, wpf, restart

Im working on a wpf application using blend 4.
under certain conditions, i need to restart the app.

Im currently using the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

which works.

My problem is that the current instance closes before the new one is loaded, making it look like the program crashed. I used the thread.sleep to stall the shutdoen, but the timing is different.

Is there any way to wait for the new process to start before shutting down the current one?

something along the lines of:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);

if (newProcess.IsLoaded == true)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Edit:

The context of this being when settings are changed, i need to restart the application to apply the changes, and I would use a splash screen to say (applying new settings please wait) and this would display until the new process is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about that: Pass old process id as a start parameter to new instance and let new instance to kill old one when it's loaded.

Use `Process.GetCurrentProcess` method to read old instance pid. Pass the parameter to new instance using `Arguments` property in `ProcessStartInfo`. Then use `Process.GetProcessById` in new instance to get and kill old instance when the argument is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call [WaitForInputIdle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2.aspx) on the newly created Process:

```
Process p = Process.Start(...);
p.WaitForInputIdle();
Application.Current.MainWindow.Close(); // perhaps better than Shutdown
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Process[] myProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName); 
    foreach (Process process in myProcess) 
    {
        if (process.Id != Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks Clemens.. i understood that i was voilating single-
entry, single-exit rule.